# Сколько звуков в слове "съел"?

Tags: фонетика

Дочка ходит в первый класс. Дали сделать звуко-буквенной анализ слова **съел**.
Я написала: 4 буквы и 4 звука (полагая, что буква **е** после твердого знака дает два звука — **й** и **э**). Но сегодня посмотрела в тетрадь, а там исправление от учительницы — не четыре звука, а три!
Кто прав? И объясните, почему.

Comment: Мы не выполняем задания, но можем проверить __уже выполненное _вами___. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавив свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 5):

> Кто прав?

Конечно, правы Вы.

Предложите учительнице прочитать вот эти строки из учебника [**Литневской**](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part1.htm#4_2):

> Твердый знак выполняет в русском языке разделительную функцию –
>   указывает, что после согласного йотированная гласная буква обозначает
>   не мягкость согласного, а два звука: *я – [й’а], **е – [й’э]**, ё – [й’о],
>   ю – [й’у] (объять [абй’а́т’], **съест [сй’эст]**, съёмка [сй’о́мка])*.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение.  Раз учительница исправила я думала, что чего-то не понимаю или есть какие-то исключения.  Но вы развеяли мои сомнения.